# Why does some code run faster than others?

Tags: r, function, timing, microbenchmark

I wrote 3 functions that all do the same thing and im wondering why when i microbenchmarked them, the one that I thought was going to be the fastest wasnt. Below is my code and i was just wondering if someone could help explain why mymean was the fastest.

```
#First remove all non numeric columns
numeric_clean_usnews <- cleaned_us_news[,-c((1:3),36)] #Removing any non numeric columns

#using apply and mean()
Average_1 <-apply(numeric_clean_usnews,2,mean,na.rm=T)
Average_1

#using apply and user created mean function
mymean <- function(cleaned_us){
  column_total = sum(cleaned_us,na.rm=T)
  column_length = sum(!is.na(cleaned_us))
  return (column_total/column_length)
}

Average_2 <- apply(numeric_clean_usnews,2,mymean)
Average_2


#using 2 for loops 
mymean2 <- function (cleaned_usnews){
  column_averages = numeric(dim(cleaned_us_news_only_numeric)[2])
for (column in 1:ncol(cleaned_us_news_only_numeric)){
  column_total = 0
  column_length = 0

  for (row in 1:nrow(cleaned_us_news_only_numeric)){

    if(!is.na(cleaned_us_news_only_numeric[row,column])){
      column_total = column_total + cleaned_us_news_only_numeric[row,column]
      column_length= column_length + 1
    }
  }
  column_averages[column]=column_total/column_length
}
  return (column_averages)
}
Average_3 <- mymean2(numeric_clean_usnews)
```

[image: Microbenchmarking]

Comment: a lazy answer: myMean is faster than `mean` because `sum` has less overhead than `mean`. It does less checking for stuff than the `mean` function. Both `sum` and `mean` ultimately run compiled c loops, which are referred to as vectorized functions. Any time you can use a vectorized function, you should as they tend to be the most optimized. `for` loops get a bad rap in R. They used to be slow, but have significant improved in speed over the past 10 years. However, they are still far slower than a vectorized function.

Comment: what kind of checks make sum faster than mean?

Comment: You can take a look at `mean.default`. Just type that into your console without parentheses. The `.default` leads to another slow-down called "method dispatch" which is related to finding the correct function (method in object oriented programming terminology) to apply to a particular object based on its class. Hadley's advanced R book and accompanying website discuss method dispatch in the object oriented programming  chapter.